# Download multiple files from Web

Tags: vb.net

I am working on some application to download files of stock prices for different dates from url. I am using the following code

```
Conn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=RA;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Conn.Open()
    End If
    Dim mont As Date
    mont = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim dnldurlA As String = "http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/"
    Dim dnldurlB As String = UCase(mont.ToString("MMM"))
    Dim dnldurlC As String = "/"
    Dim dnldurlD As String = "cm"
    Dim dnldurlE As String = mont.ToString("dd")
    Dim dnldurlF As String = mont.ToString("yyyy")
    Dim dnldurlG As String = "bhav"
    Dim dnldurlH As String = ".csv"
    Dim dnldurlI As String = ".zip"
    Dim dnldurlJ As String = "\"
    Dim FileName As String = dnldurlE & dnldurlB & dnldurlF & ".ZIP"
    Try
        Dim downloadClient As New WebClient()
        downloadClient.Headers("Accept") = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        downloadClient.Headers("User-Agent") = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1"
        Dim dnldurl As String = dnldurlA & dnldurlF & dnldurlC & dnldurlB & dnldurlC & dnldurlD & dnldurlE & dnldurlB & dnldurlF & dnldurlG & dnldurlH & dnldurlI
        downloadClient.DownloadFile(New Uri(dnldurl), ("C:\" & FileName))
        While (downloadClient.IsBusy = True)

        End While
        downloadClient.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("File can not be downloaded!!!")
        Me.Close()
    End Try
```

I am stuck with after downloading the first file, when I selected the file for another date, it throws an error 
{"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}
But when I exit the application and try again for the same date, the file is downloaded promptly.

Please help

Thanks in advance
Kris

Comment: It could be some sort of protection the site added to prevent people from downloading to many things to quickly. Some site only want people to browse and offer an API to download the information.

Comment: I made some tweaks to the codes. Anyway it was haunting for quite some time. Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are doing something like that in a loop, you can just add a small delay to avoid being throttled.

Comment: I am not a hard core developer, still this is not in any loop every time once a file is downloaded I have to select the file for the next date. Thanks to the_lotus it was some kind protection of the web site and some small changes it worked. I tried with delay also but didn't work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I just made a small change and it worked perfectly

```
Conn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=RA;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Conn.Open()
    End If
    Dim mont As Date
    mont = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim dnldurlA As String = "http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/"
    Dim dnldurlB As String = UCase(mont.ToString("MMM"))
    Dim dnldurlC As String = "/"
    Dim dnldurlD As String = "cm"
    Dim dnldurlE As String = mont.ToString("dd")
    Dim dnldurlF As String = mont.ToString("yyyy")
    Dim dnldurlG As String = "bhav"
    Dim dnldurlH As String = ".csv"
    Dim dnldurlI As String = ".zip"
    Dim dnldurlJ As String = "\"
    Dim FileName As String = dnldurlE & dnldurlB & dnldurlF & ".ZIP"
    Try
       Dim downloadClient As New WebClient()
       Dim dnldurl As String = dnldurlA & dnldurlF & dnldurlC & dnldurlB & dnldurlC & dnldurlD & dnldurlE & dnldurlB & dnldurlF & dnldurlG & dnldurlH & dnldurlI
       downloadClient.DownloadFile(New Uri(dnldurl), ("C:\" & FileName))
       While (downloadClient.IsBusy = True)

        End While
        downloadClient.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("File can not be downloaded!!!")
        Me.Close()
    End Try
```

Thanks